# Write newline to csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I want to end each interation of a for loop with writing a new line of content (including newline) to a csv file. I have this:

```
# Set up an output csv file with column headers
with open('outfile.csv','w') as f:
    f.write("title; post")
    f.write("\n")
```

This does not appear to write an actual \n (newline) the file. Further:

```
    # Concatenate into a row to write to the output csv file
    csv_line = topic_title + ";" + thread_post
    with open('outfile.csv','w') as outfile:
                 outfile.write(csv_line + "\n")
```

This, also, does not move the cursor in the outfile to the next line. Each new line, with every iteration of the loop, just overwrites the most recent one.

I also tried `outfile.write(os.linesep)` but did not work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

change 'w' to 'a'

```
with open('outfile.csv','a')
```

Comment: Why would this work ? Can you explain how changing the access modifier alters the EOL character? Why wouldn't write('\n') work ?

Comment: I think OP is opening/closing the file within a loop (they mention a loop but don't show where it is), so opening in append mode is a "fix", but is *the wrong way*.

Comment: Yes, that's a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
with open('outfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.writerow(...)
```

Alternatively:

```
f = csv.writer('outfile.csv', lineterminator='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

I confront with same problem，  only need follow:

```
  f = csv.writer('outfile.csv', lineterminator='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using python2 then use

```
with open('xxx.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

If you are using python3 make use of `newline=''`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with: `open(output_file_name.csv, 'a+', newline='') as f:`