# Reading CSV results in nested list and needs repairs - more efficient way needed

Tags: python, performance, csv

**The problem:** 
My program reads a CSV file and produces a nested list (because there are no line breaks) and I need to 'repair' the list afterwards before I can go further. The code works, but I am struggling to find a more efficient way and would be interested in any suggestions.

**The details:**

My program reads a CSV file which has the following format:

> hakcke39475728,fjfjalcl689920,vjgjvkv848291, ...

So each item contains of letters and numbers, with a comma as the delimiter and no new lines inbetween. I use csv to read the file and put the result into a list:

```
import csv

result = []
with open("input.csv", "r", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    result = list(reader)
```

As there are no line breaks, the result is a nested list in the following format:

> [['hakcke39475728', 'fjfjalcl689920', 'vjgjvkv848291', '...'], []]

After this, I need to "clean up" and perform an extra step - a for loop -  to unnest the list:

```
output_final = [] 
for item in result[0]:
    output_final.append(item)
```

To finally get the output I need:

> ['hakcke39475728', 'fjfjalcl689920', 'vjgjvkv848291', '...']

**What would be a more efficient way?**

I couldn't figure out how to read the CSV in a different way so that it does not result in a nested list. AFAIK there is no way to set a comma as the EOL character (which would resolve my problem here, as I do not have line endings inbetween my values in the input.

Possibly related questions:

- I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733205/write-newline-to-csv-in-python/43733244), but it's about writing the CSV differently, not reading it and not possible in my case.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652131/python-csv-import-with-nested-list-creation) is asking for a nested list instead of wanting to get rid of it, but there's no way to reverse-engineer the solution.

Comment: Couldn't you simply access your results with list(reader)[0]?

Comment: Yes, thanks. That's what I am doing right now. I added the code snippet of my repair, which is exactly this. I am just wondering whether this actually is the most efficient way to do it, or if I am missing something here.

Comment: It seems like you have a file of single entries separated by commas, so `open("input.csv", "r", newline="").split(',')` might be enough.

Comment: You dont actually need a for loop. simply output_final = list(reader)[0] will work. Also probably the change to the csv reader by snakecharmerb will work cleaner.

Comment: JasonChia - yes, your suggestion works. Thanks.
@snakecharmerb - I get an error when trying your suggestion: _AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'_ - will need to look into this as I couldn't figure out a fix right now. Any suggestions?

Comment: My bad, you need to rad the file  `open("input.csv", "r", newline="").read().split(',')`

Comment: It still throws an exception, but the error text just says `__enter__`. However, see the answer below: using next(reader) resolved the issue!

Comment: One possibility (without CSV module) is to use `f.readline().strip().split(',')`  if there is only one line and no formatting problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After this, I need to "clean up" and perform an extra step - a for loop - to unnest the list:

There is no need to copy the items one by one into a new list.

```
output_final = result[0]
```

---

Alternatively / with more context, under the assumption that your CSV file really only ever will contain one line of data:

```
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r", encoding="utf8", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    result = next(reader)
```

A csv reader is an iterator - it iterates over the rows in the CSV file. Normally you would use iterators in `for` loops:

```
    for row in reader:
        ...
```

The main difference to a list is that you can't directly access the elements of an iterator: `reader[0]` won't work. But the `next()` function retrieves the next element from an iterator every time you call it.

In this case, `next(reader)` is only called once and therefore you get the first "row" of your data.

A note about `newline=""`. That does not mean that there are no newlines. It means that the `csv` module will handle newlines for you and automatically adapt to Windows-, Mac-, or *nix-style newlines. When dealing with the `csv` module, you should always open files with `newline=""` because of that.

Comment: Thanks! Using next(reader) did the trick, it creates exactly the list I need.

Comment: @ladyfrauke Keep `next()` in mind for other cases when you deal with CSV data. For example you can use it to skip the header row in a CSV reader - `next(reader)` advances the reader by one, and then you can call `for row in reader:` to go over the remainder of the data.